# React meaning of () =>()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am new to react and need to learn that and I have method like this

```
const test = (e) => {
 e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And I am little bit confused in what are the way correct way to call this and reason ?

```
={(e) => test(e)} or ={test} or {test(e)}
```

Comment: `() => ()` isn't meaningful ... but then, none of the code you've shown does that - if it's the `=>` you don't understand, that's an arrow function

Comment: `onClick={test}` usually